# Dynamically generated content for html page after button click

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, python-3.x, flask

I have html page where I want to open dialog by button click and content of dialog should be dynamically generated.

The idea is the following:

1. I click button
2. JS(ajax)run my flask route , where http request to other site is executed and then json is returned
3. The returned json is passed to js (or html), then this json is parsed and according to found information, the elements (images as an example) are displayed in opened dialog

Python:

```
@app.route('/sales_inventory', methods=['POST'])
def tm_inventory(user):
    response = some_function("authKey")
return make_response(jsonify(response)))
```

HTML:

```
<button class="inventory">Inventory</button>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Elements should be generated inside div .modal-content

JS:

```
$(."inventory").click(function () {
    $.ajax({data: {
        user: $(this).next().text()
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/sales_inventory'
 })
```

Js is not completed, because I have no idea how should it be

Answer (score 1):

The class name and `.` should be wrapped by a string quotation. In your code the class indicator `.` is outside the string quotation.

According to your question your server is responding JSON data, so you should add dataType as `JSON` of your [**AJAX**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Also add a success callback function which is automatically called when the server response. Of success function there is a parameter `data` which contains the response data as an object (JSON) and now using this data you can prepare your HTML and set in the certain place of the modal.

**JS:**

```
$(".inventory").click(function () {
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            user: $(this).next().text()
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/sales_inventory',
        success: function(data) {
            // var prepared_html = using `data`
            // $('.modal-body').html(prepared_html);
        }
    })
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, it's just a typo during question creation